# Where can I contact roblox support (a real person)?

Tags: roblox

Can someone tell me how to contact Roblox support? I don't mean [roblox.com/support](https://roblox.com/support), that's just a bot. I want to talk to a real human who works in Roblox support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can contact a real person by dialing 888-858-2569 to contact Roblox customer service.** The line is available at all times, but it uses an automated voicemail system, which means it might take a little bit for them to get to you and call you back. This line is normally used for very specific or confusing questions.